# How to retain the textbox text when page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have two textbox and one button in one page,these textbox located into panel.And also this page refresh automatically wvery one minute.Now i enter any text into textbox,and i didnot to click anything in that page.so this case after one minute that text in textbox cleared automatically.how to handle this problem.i dont want any button click event.just when page load,that text not cleared,how to retain this text in textbox.but i thing hidden field is possible to work with jquery,but its not work for me.That is in page load,the hidden field value is empty.So textbox not retain the text value.Anyone know please help me.

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
                        <div class="full" id="tab-1">
                            <div class="tabbedData">
                                <table width="97%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="tblForm">
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td width="19%">
                                                Company Name
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="36%">
                                  <asp:TextBox ID="txtCompanyName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="17%">
                                                Contact
                                            </td>
                                            <td width="28%">
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtContact" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                Mr./Mis./...
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtHonorfic" runat="server" Style="width: 70px;"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                Phone
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                 </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
  </asp:Panel>
```

My Jquery Code like page refresh,page name is Customer.aspx

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        window.setInterval(yourfunction, 60000);
    });
 function yourfunction() { window.location = "Customer.aspx"; }
```

Comment: use a `ViewModel` to pass data from `View` to `Controller`

Comment: use `viewstate` if you are usinig asp textboxes

Comment: I tried viewstate,but its not work for me

Comment: can you provide code?

Comment: Anyone give me solution please

Comment: store text values in session and assign it to your textbox after page refresh.

Comment: Why do you want to refresh the page, but keep the texts? If you want to keep the texts, just don't refresh the page?

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1**
Add a hidden fake button in your page. and click on it through javascript when you want to refresh that page.

```
<div style="display:none"><asp:Button runat="server" id="btnFake"></asp:Button></div>


function RefreshPage(){
    $("#<%= btnFake.ClientID %>").click();
}
```

**Approach 2**
Maintain a web-method on server which will be periodically called from the web-page through ajax method which will watch for changes made in web-page,
the method will accept the parameters and set the session values,
set the field values from session when the page reloads

Comment: Don't want to click any button to refresh,its automatically refresh in my page.this case when i enter the text into textbox how to maintain it when page load.

Comment: you cant maintain it until you post the values back to server, simply setting `window.location` will just reload the page

Comment: ok.But in my project need refresh automatically,that's why ask.Then there is no any way to maintain it?